# "Syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)", mesmo sem erro aparente

Tags: php

Está dando esse erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Hugg\sys\historico.php on line 3

Estou a um bom tempo procurando a solução mais não consigo achar. O erro esta nessa linha:

```
if(isset($_POST['mensagem'])){
```

O código:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
    if(isset($_POST['mensagem'])){
        include_once "../defines.php";
        require_once('../classes/BD.class.php');
        BD::conn();

        $mensagens = array();
        $id_conversa = (int)$_POST['conversacom'];
        $online = (int)$_POST['online'];

        $pegaConversas = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mensagens` WHERE (`id_de` = ? AND `id_para` = ?) OR (`id_de` = ? AND `id_para` = ?) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");
        $pegaConversas->execute(array($online, $id_conversa, $id_conversa, $online));

        while($row = $pegaConversas->fetch()){
            $fotoUser = '';
            if($online == $row['id_de']){
                $janela_de = $row['id_para'];

            }elseif($online == $row['id_para']){
                $janela_de = $row['id_de'];

                $pegaFoto = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT `foto` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `id` = '".$row['id_de']."'");
                $pegaFoto->execute();

                while ($usr = $pegaFoto->fetch()){
                    $fotoUser = ($usr['foto'] == '') ? 'default.jpg' : $usr['foto'];
                }
            }

            $emotions = array(':P', ':$', ':|', ':O', '<3', ';*', ':%', ':@', ':D', ';D', ':A', ':"(', ':(', ':Z');
            $imgs = array(
                '<img src="smiles/tongue.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/redface.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/nada.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/espanto.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/blowkiss.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/kiss.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/zangado.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/mad.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/rindo.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/rindo2.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/anjo.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/choro.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/triste.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>',
                '<img src="smiles/dormindo.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"/>'
            );
            $msg = str_replace($emotions, $imgs, $row['mensagem']);
            $mensagens[] = array(
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'mensagem' => utf8_encode($msg),
                'fotoUser' => $fotoUser,
                'id_de' => $row['id_de'],
                'id_para' => $row['id_para'],
                'janela_de' => $janela_de
            );
        }
        die(json_encode($mensagens));
    }
```

Postei ele completo [aqui](https://pastebin.com/bhKfF8nm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quase todo editor de código tem uma opção de mostrar espaços e quebras de linha, se ativar a opção no seu editor durante a edição (ao menos quando surgir este tipo de problema), provavelmente vai localizar mais fácil essas coisas.

Dá para ver copiando do seu [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/bhKfF8nm) e colando num editor de código que você tem um caractere especial invisível (nulo) no fim da linha do header.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
                                                       ^^ --- AQUI
    if(isset($_POST['mensagem'])){
        include_once "../defines.
```

Veja o arquivo aberto num visualizador hexadecimal:

[image: Hexdump mostrando caractere 0x00 no fim da linha]

<sub>Usei essa excelente ferramenta gratuita: https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/</sub>

Uma das soluções mais simples para o seu caso é por o cursor antes do `;`, deletar até juntar as duas linhas ficando assim:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8")f(isset($_POST['mensagem'])){
               É pra deletar até colar tudo mesmo ---^^
```

(isto tudo para ter certeza que deletou os caracteres invisíveis).

Uma vez feito isso, dê <kbd>ENTER</kbd> entre as linhas novamente, reponha o `;` na linha de cima e o `i` do `if` que o problema deve ser sanado.